# How to determine where Load Test results are saved in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, testing, load-testing

I'm running some load tests using Visual Studio 2010.  I haven't been able to figure out how to set where the test results are saved, and it seems that I have no test results to browse once the test runs.

I have the general idea that you're supposed to supply a SQL connection string specifying a SQL server with some tables set up on it.

Where do I set the connection string for local test runs?  Is it possible to configure VS2k10 to save my test results to a file locally?

Please note that local SQL databases such as SQL Express are specifically forbidden in my environment.

Answer (score 5):

If you find yourself in a situation where you didn't setup the database to store the test results from the VS 2010 Load Tester, the following will help.

The default install of VS 2010, won't have the **Microsoft Visual Studio Test Controller 2010** tool.

To create the necessary tables to store the test results, all you need to do is run the **loadtestresultsrepository.sql** script against your database.

You'll find this script at:
x86 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\Common7\IDE
x64 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Taken from:
[MSDN: How to: Create a Load Test Results Repository Using SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182600.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio strictly requires SQL Server for the load test store.  If you don't have a SQL Server database, you cannot save test run data.  All you can do is browse the result immediately after a test run, and perhaps copy-and-paste the test details into Excel.  After you close the result, it's gone for good.

However, the database does not have to be on your local machine.  Is there any chance you can get access to SQL Server somewhere else on your network?

You have to run "Microsoft Visual Studio Test Controller 2010 Configuration Tool" (found in Visual Studio start menu folder) to configure the database before use.

Setting the connection string is done in Test (menu) > Manage Test Controllers.  This dialog allows you to select the Controller (or 'Local - No controller' for local tests) and also allows you to set the connection string to the load test results store.